# Linux to Windows ping

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ping

ALL,

I have a LAN with the laptops running different OS. Also on Windows up until couple of days ago I was successfully using ZoneAlarm.

However I recently installed MS SQL Server 2012 Express on one of the Windows machine running Windows 8.1 and set it up to accept remote connections. This in turn required to open a port 1433 on that machine, since that is the default poty SQLServer is listening on. Unfortunately this operation is not possible with ZA, so I installed CoMoDo. Next I added all my computers IP in the Trusted Zone of the CoMoDo.

Next I tried to do the following:

```
busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433
```

That command didn't produce the connection.

So I tried the ping:

```
ping 192.168.1.4
```

That resulted in 100% packet loss.

However when I do a reverse ping - from Windows to Linux everything works.

What am I missing? Is there some specific setting in CoMoDo that I need to set to allow traffic? The port is already been open in the CoMoDo firewall - I just need the traffic/communication to be working.

[EDIT]

I just tried to turn off CoMoDo and Windows Firewall and then connect from Linux using "busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433". The connection still failed. Which means that I will not be able to connect remotely to my SQL Server 2012.

So how do I see what the problem is?

[/EDIT]

Comment: To see if it's really Comodo (and ZA) that's blocking the traffic, try disabling it and pinging again.  If that doesn't change the behavior, you may look in your router's log/settings.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your Win firewall has ICMP/ping turned off.
To enable:

Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

Then in Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4 
on the same panel go to customize, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "echo request"

Do the "save/enable" dance.

Retry your ping from Linux.

Comment: @PHeffner, I did that and also I did open ICMP on CoMoDo. Now, ping comes in. However, telnet still can't connect: "Can't connect to remote host. Connection timed out". The command is: busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433". Any idea?

Comment: According to Microsoft:  Open a command prompt window. Click Start, type cmd in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
Type the following command:
pkgmgr /iu:”TelnetServer”
If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.
When the command prompt appears again, the installation is complete.

Comment: @PHeffner, I installed TelnetServer, but still can't connect. Same error: "Connection timed out". I guess its firewall...

Comment: Also, see my edit.